# How to get out variable from recurrence in Java?

Tags: java, recurrence

This is a method in Java, that(when k == 0) in int[] arr has one of k-combination int[] intems. In variable iloczyn is calculated product of elements in this combination. In tmp is calculated sum of all such products. Unfortunately, System.out.println(tmp) shows, that when function ends, tmp equals 0. This is very sad, because i need this variable for next calculations. What shoud I do?

```
int tmp = 0;
public void kcomb(int[] items, int n, int k, int[] arr) 
{
    int iloczyn = 1;


    if (k == 0) {
        for(int i = 0; i< arr.length; i++){
            iloczyn*=arr[i];
        }
        tmp +=iloczyn;


    } else {
        for (int i = n; i <= items.length - k; i++) {
            arr[arr.length - k] = items[i];
            kcomb(items, i + 1, k - 1, arr);
        }
    }
    System.out.println(tmp);
}
```

Comment: Use the debugger to find out what your code is doing?

Comment: For better help sooner, try posting an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)

Answer (score 3):

Recursive methods can be tricky.  You're getting burned because you aren't handling the return value of the method very well.  In fact, there isn't one at all.

First, do as @olicharlesworth recommends and debug through your code. It'll be enlightening.

Then, to fix this, consider that your routine basically has 2 pieces that never meet - the k==0 piece and the other.  Each of these sections should initialize the tmp value, calculate the tmp value that's appropriate for that section *and return it to the caller*.

Then the problematic instance *tmp* variable will be a non-issue.

Answer (score 2):

Well, the method doesn't always print 0 -- I [tested it](http://ideone.com/wFOkl) and for inputs `{1, 3, 5, 7}, 3, 1, {4, 3, 2, 1}` it prints 168 (twice). Of course I have no idea whether these inputs make any sense at all.

You should think through the logic and see whether the code is actually doing what you think it should do. @TonyEnnis is right that using return values rather than a side-effect would make this much better (both to understand and in terms of coding practice).

Answer (score 1):

Is any value in arr[] equal to zero?  If that's true, then this block:

```
for(int i = 0; i< arr.length; i++){
        iloczyn*=arr[i];
}
```

...will always produce a zero.  If the first value is zero, then iloczyn * 0 = 0, and all subsequent iterations will equal zero as well.  The same thing happens if any values in the array are zero...they'll force iloczyn to set to zero every time.

Step through the code and double-check the values of arr[], just to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm missing something, you only set tmp when k==0.  k doesn't change, so it must be non-zero when the method is called.

Comment: `k` does "change" -- there's a recursive call in there.